# Differential evolution multiple constraints for beginners

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

i'm trying to optimize the following function with scipy optimize differential_evolution:

```
def obj_fun_cal(x,df_TZ_input,df_TZ_target):
v=(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10],x[11],x[12],x[13],x[14],x[15],x[16],x[17],x[18],x[19],x[20])
prodmx=df_TZ_input*v
sum_vector=prodmx.sum(axis=1)
MAE=np.mean(np.absolute(df_TZ_target-sum_vector))
penalty=0
if x[1]<=x[0]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[2]<=x[1]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[3]<=x[2]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[4]<=x[3]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[5]<=x[4]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[6]<=x[5]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[7]<=x[6]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[8]<=x[7]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[9]<=x[8]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[10]<=x[9]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[11]<=x[10]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[12]<=x[11]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[13]<=x[12]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[14]<=x[13]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[15]<=x[14]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[16]<=x[15]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[17]<=x[16]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[18]<=x[17]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[19]<=x[18]:
    penalty+=1000
if x[20]<=x[19]:
    penalty+=1000

     
eval_num=MAE+penalty
return eval_num
```

The code runs fine with DE but i'm searching a more inteligent way to force the fact that evey variable must be greater than the previous.
I'd like to use the Constraint argument but i don't know how to write linear constraints in the proper sintax. I've seen people using dictionaries, other using dedicated functions (always with Minimize...unfortunately no example with DE) and i'm pretty confused..and stuck :P

If anyone could provide a piece of code that suits this problem it would be of tremendous help.

Thank you

PS: edited with suggested method result in f(x)=inf

Answer (score 1):

You can write your constraints in matrix form `-infty <= B @ x <= 0`, where `@` denotes the matrix multiplication and B is the matrix

```
( -1  1  0  0 0 .... 0  0)
( 0  -1  1  0 0 .... 0  0)
( 0   0 -1  1 0 .... 0  0)
( .                      )
( .                      )
( .                      )
( 0   0  0  0 0 .... -1 1)
( 0   0  0  0 0 ....  0 0)
```

Then you only need to pass a constraint:

```
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint, differential_evolution

# Assuming (n,) is the shape of x and v
B = np.eye(n, k = 1) - np.eye(n)
B[-1,-1] = 0.0

# Define the constraint: -np.inf <= B @ x <= 0.0
def constr_fun(x): return B @ x
nlc = NonlinearConstraint(constr_fun, -np.inf, 0.0)

# Your objective function
def obj_fun_cal(x,df_TZ_input,df_TZ_target):
    v = (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10],x[11],x[12],x[13],x[14],x[15],x[16],x[17],x[18],x[19],x[20])
    prodmx = df_TZ_input*v
    sum_vector = prodmx.sum(axis=1)
    MAE = np.mean(np.absolute(df_TZ_target-sum_vector))
    return MAE

# Pass the constraint..
result = differential_evolution(obj_fun_cal, args=(df_TZ_input, df_TZ_target), constraints=nlc)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @joni, unfortunately i'm not very keen on using lambda. it would be possible to do without it?

Comment: @Steve Sure, I edited my answer. Note that a lambda is just an anonymous function, i.e. `f = lambda x: x**2` is the same as `def f(x): return x**2`.

Comment: Thanks, i've used your code and it work without errors but now DE returns f(x)=inf at each step. How do i handle that?

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to help without knowing `df_TZ_input` and `df_TZ_target`

Comment: i think the problem is B = np.eye(n, k = 1) - np.eye(n) that creates a squared matrix wich last element n,n is -1 and not 1 as you stated at the beginning.

Comment: Indeed, there was a mistake in the matrix B. I edited the answer. Providing a MWE makes it much easier to reproduce the error and to thereby easier to help. A description of the data is not a MWE.